# iOS8: Are apps on the multitasking screen in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can see apps when I double tap the home button to open the multitasking screen. Does it means the apps are in background? I need to make sure if "(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions" method is not called when I tap an app on the multitasking screen.

I think that many apps remain on the multitasking screen. Some apps are launched at three month ago. I do not believe such apps are still remaining in memory.

Comment: For most of them; they're probably not running - it's a history stack of apps. Please read the [application lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) document, which tells you what all the states are - figure 2-3 is the most pertinent here. You will not receive the `dFLWO` message if the app is still running when you swap back to it if it was not terminated.

Comment: Thanks. " it's a history stack of apps". yes I guess so too. I want to see the document about the multitasking screen. Do you know the official name of the screen. I will try to find it....

Comment: Apple refers to it as the [`Multitasking UI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Multitasking.html).

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions"
```

method does not call when app start again from the multitasking screen.

Comment: Thanks. Petesh said the multitasking screen is probably just a history stack of apps. But don't you think it?

Comment: Petesh said right that 'all apps running' remains in the stack. only apps are exchange state between background and foreground.

Comment: App states has 5 states:Not running、Inactive、Active、Background、and Suspended. Do you think that the state of the apps in the stack are always only Background or Suspended state?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Figure 2-3  State changes in an iOS app

See this image: http://imgur.com/edit

Answer (score 0):

When you totally minimised the app, We can say that app is in background.

If **App A** is open. Now you are double tap on Home button. Other minimised apps will be display there. From that selection of app. Suppose you select **App B**,

**App A** --> Background And **App B** --> Foreground

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks. Yes. you are completely right. I agree with you. I just didn't know how can I call the state of the apps on the multitasking app.